# Correlation Id errors for Kafka console producer

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, authorization, kafka-producer-api

I have started a standalone kafka server(version 2.11-0.11.0.1) with 1 node and 1 zookeeper, i am trying to implement ssl with acls but unable to produce.
Performed the following steps:

1. **Started kafka node using following configurations ie (server.properties):**

   broker.id=0
       listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092,SSL://127.0.0.1:9093
       advertised.listeners=SSL://127.0.0.1:9093
       num.network.threads=3
       num.io.threads=8
       socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
       socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
       socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
       log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
       num.partitions=1
       num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
       offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
       transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
       transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
       log.segment.bytes=1073741824
       zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
       zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
       group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
       ssl.keystore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/kaf-
   new/server.keystore.jks
       ssl.keystore.password=test1234
       ssl.key.password=test1234
       ssl.truststore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/kaf-
   new/server.truststore.jks
       ssl.truststore.password=test1234
       authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
       allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
       super.users=User:CN=jewel,OU=atos,O=atos,L=mum,ST=maha,C=in
       ssl.client.auth=required
       ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
       ssl.keystore.type=JKS
       ssl.truststore.type=JKS
       inter.broker.listener.name=SSL
2. **Modified producer.properties as follows:**

   bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
   compression.type=none
   ssl.keystore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/prod/server.keystore.jks
   ssl.keystore.password=test123
   ssl.key.password=test123
   security.protocol=SSL
   ssl.truststore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/kaf-new/client.truststore.jks
   ssl.truststore.password=test1234
   ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
   ssl.keystore.type=JKS
   ssl.truststore.type=JKS
3. **Have create the ACLS at zookeeper with following command**:

   ```
   bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=jewel,OU=atos,O=atos,L=mum,ST=maha,C=in --producer --topic
   ```

   securing-hey
4. **Try producing to topics with following command:**

   bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic  securing-hey --producer.config config/producer.properties
5. **It Fails with the following error:**

WARN Connection to node -1 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Can you please suggest what can i do to proceed further, your help will be appreciated .